# Cannot define namespace variable which was defined globally TCL

Tags: tcl

I cannot define variables in namespace (in TCL) which was defined previously in global scope. See my example:

```
xsct% $tcl_version
[8.5]
xsct% set foo 1
1
xsct% $foo
[1]
xsct% namespace eval ns {
set foo 2
set bar 3
}
3
xsct% $::ns::bar
[3]
xsct% $::ns::foo
can't read "::ns::foo": no such variable
xsct%
```

I have reproduced the issue online: http://tpcg.io/3SIBYG

How can I define variables in namespaces independently from global scope?

I use:

- Win10
- TCL 8.5 in Xilinx's XSCT TCL console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always define variables in a namespace with the `variable` command at least the first time you access them, otherwise you end up with *namespace variable resolution rules* taking over and making your life unpleasant. They're weird (though actually very similar to how command resolution works) and you virtually never want them, and may get removed in Tcl 9. But until then, you're stuck doing:

```
namespace eval ns {
    variable foo 2
    variable bar 3
}
```

or:

```
namespace eval ns {
    variable foo
    set foo 2
    variable bar
    set bar 3
}
```

If you want to do arrays, you can. Do them like this (with only one argument to `variable`):

```
namespace eval ns {
    variable ary
    array set ary {foo 2 bar 3}
}
```

What the `variable` command actually does is make the variable in the namespace *in `unset` state* so that it still resolves when commands like `set` and `array` can find the variable and write to it.

Comment: Namespace variable resolution rules are sometimes referred to by Tcl's developers as one of the crazy aunties in Tcl's attic. You _really_ don't want to deal with them, and their existence has lead to a number of subtle bugs even in Tcl's implementation in the past due to just how thoroughly unintuitive they are to people…